# How to achieve URL redirection or XSS with code mentioned

Tags: javascript, url, redirect, dom, xss

I have a web application which has below javascript code.

```
location.pathname = location.pathname.replace(/^\/\//, '/');
```

As per my understanding the above code will lead to DOM based open URL re-dicrection or DOM XSS security issues.

I have tried different vector combinations but failed achieve the goal to find a successful PoC to prove the security issue.

Requesting your help here.. thanks.